# Getting error resulting in crash loop elasticsearch (GCE/kubernetes)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

im getting an error while running elasticsearch on kubernetes. I dont believe this is a memory allocation issue but i dont know. Trying to set it up with discovery - not a single node.

here is my kubernetes config for elasticsearch - https://hastebin.com/ohiyivinit.bash

Here is my error on startup from `kubectl logs`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: starting java failed with [137]
output:

error:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.flagsFinal(JvmErgonomics.java:111)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.finalJvmOptions(JvmErgonomics.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:89)
```

EDIT: my error was that the requested memory was the same as the max memory in limits

Answer (score 0):

The error code [strongly suggests this is a memory issue](https://success.docker.com/article/what-causes-a-container-to-exit-with-code-137).

Since you're using GKE, if Stackdriver is enabled, you can use the following [advanced filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters) to confirm if this is an OOM kill:

```
resource.type="container"
resource.labels.cluster_name="YOUR_CLUSTER"
resource.labels.namespace_id="NAMESPACE"
resource.labels.project_id="PROJECT_ID"
resource.labels.zone:"ZONE"
resource.labels.container_name="CONTAINER_NAME" # Container name, not pod name
resource.labels.pod_id:"POD_NAME-" # Notice that is not the full pod ID
"OOM"
```

If you find out this is an OOM issue, you can set [requests and limits](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits) to your deployment to ensure the resources are enough to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCetb.png)Try to run command prompt run as administartor